# Как передать переменную из приложения на C# в javascript сайта

Tags: javascript, c#

Как технически реализовать, чтобы приложение на C# под Windows открывало браузер со сторонним сайтом, и при этом надо передать переменную из C# и получить ее в javascript сайта, который реализован на JavaScript и PHP.

Comment: [Это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27252991/312041)?

Comment: У меня сайт не на asp.net а на php и javascript

Comment: коду по ссылке, что я вам дал, без разницы, на чем у вас сайт

Comment: То есть надо из C# запустить браузер и передать переменную в https строке?

Comment: Вы же пишете приложение под windows? Если оно у вас настольное, то можно в окно этого приложения встроить веб браузер, и через этот веб браузер загрузить сайт и выполнять на сайте произвольный javascript код

Comment: Просто я учусь на php javascript, а C# не знаю, я делаю платежку на сайте, а из приложения Windows мне надо получить ник клиента.

Comment: Ну тогда делайте запрос на ваш сайт из приложения, в урл передавайте ник, какие проблемы с этим?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85013/discussion-between-valeriy-petukhov-and-tym32167).

Comment: у меня уже ночь, я в чат не пойду, а пойду глядеть сны :) Что вам могу посоветовать - это детально описать в вопросе что вам надо сделать, что вы пробовали и что не получилось - так как сейчас вообще не ясна ваша задача, потому вам никто ответ не напишет